# Is there a cleaner way to write this Clojure function that loops, updates and returns a map?

Tags: clojure

This function works, but I'm in the process of learning Clojure and want to know if there is a better/cleaner way to write this:

```
;; loop over methods, update the scripts map, and return scripts

(defn update-scripts
  [filename]
  (loop [scripts {}
         methods (get-methods filename)]
    (if (seq methods)
      (let [method (first methods)
            sig (get-method-signature method)
            name (get-method-name sig)]
        (recur (assoc scripts name {:sig sig, :method method})
               (rest methods)))
      scripts)))


(update-scripts "gremlin.groovy")
```

UPDATE: Here's what I ended up using:

```
(defn- update-scripts
  [scripts method]
  (let [sig (get-method-signature method)
        name (get-method-name sig)]
    (assoc scripts name {:sig sig :method method})))

(defn get-scripts
  [filename]
  (reduce update-scripts {} (get-methods filename)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with a reduce as follows:

```
(defn update-scripts
  [filename]
  (reduce (fn [scripts method]
            (let [sig (get-method-signature method)
                  name (get-method-name sig)]
              (assoc scripts name {:sig sig :method method})))
          {}
          (get-methods filename)))
```

This is a "pattern" I follow when I have to take a collection, and return a collection of a different type. Here we have a list of methods, and we want to convert this list into a map (after doing some processing on it). I feel reduce is the most readable way to do this.

Comment: Thanks @vedang -- I studied this tutorial on `reduce` after reading your answer: http://www.learningclojure.com/2010/08/reduce-not-scary.html

Answer (score 4):

```
(defn update-scripts
  [filename]
  (into {} (map (fn [m] [ (get-method-name (get-method-signature m)) {:sig (get-method-signature m), :method m}  ] ) (get-methods filename) )))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `map` to build a hash-map for each entry returned by `get-methods` and then `merge` all these hash-maps into one.

```
(defn update-scripts
  [filename]
  (apply merge
         (map
          #(hash-map (get-method-name %) {:sig (get-method-signature %) :method %})
          (get-methods filename))))
```

Generally it is better to use the standard sequence manipulation functions like `map`, `filter` etc. instead of a `loop`.